# How to install Microsoft.NET.Native.Runtime.2.1-rel package while sideloading an app in Microsoft Store

Tags: visual-studio, windows-store-apps, packaging, hololens

I am trying to sideload an app using visual studio 2017.
Steps I am taking:

```
Right Click on the project->Store->Create app packages-> for sideloading....
```

It does create the package.

However when i try to install the packagebundle, i have this error

> App Installer failed to install package dependencies. Ask the
>   developer for Microsoft.NET.Native.Runtime.2.1-rel package.

When i take a look at Dependencies/x86/ i have 3 packages. There is `Microsoft.NET.Native.Runtime.2.1` but not `Microsoft.NET.Native.Runtime.2.1-rel`

I found [this](https://doumer.me/how-to-resolve-microsoft-net-native-runtime-2-1-rel-not-found/) but downgrading UWP didnt help.
Anybody has an idea how to fix this?

EDIT:
After trying to downgrade uwp to an ever lower version as suggested in a comment (6.0.1) I got this other error:

> Failure reason: Windows cannot install package because this package
>   depends on a framework that could not be found. Provide the framework
>   "Microsoft.NET.Native.Framework.2.0" published by "CN=Microsoft
>   Corporation, O=Microsoft Corporation, L=Redmond, S=Washington, C=US",
>   with neutral or x86 processor architecture and minimum version
>   2.0.25709.0, along with this package to install. The frameworks with name "Microsoft.NET.Native.Framework.2.0" currently installed are: {}
>   Failure text: Package failed updates, dependency or conflict
>   validation. (0x80073cf3)

After I downgraded, it works when I install in a pc, but not in Hololens where it shows this error. (I build for x86 architecture)

**UPDATE:**
I have accepted an answer, because it pointed me in the right direction, however the latest stable version didnt work for me. I downgraded to an even lower version.
I dont know why, but it seemed to fix the issue.

Comment: Could you change the version Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform to a version lower than 6.0.8 to try again?

Comment: I tried with 6.0.8 and it didnt work. I will try with a lower version and get back to you

Comment: @DasiyTianMSFT please see my edited question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem. Later I have noticed that I have installed "**Pre-release**" version of "**Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform**" Nuget. 
Downgraded to latest stable version solved my problem.